# How to prove or disprove that an homomorphism exists?

Tags: group-theory

The question is as follows:

Give an example or show that this can't exist:

Two finite groups G and H and an group homomorphism $\phi$ from G to H, with an image $im \phi \neq e$, such that the order of G is not a devisor of the order of H.

I think I found the answer but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Let G = $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \times \mathbb{Z} / 3$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}/2$

And $\phi$ : $G \rightarrow H$ , $(a,b) \mapsto a$

Is this a correct homomorphism?

Comment: That's perfectly right.

Comment: im$\phi\neq\emptyset$ is not a restriction. What you really mean
is: im$\phi\neq0$ where $0$ denotes the trivial group. I advice
you to repair that.

Comment: Yes that was what I meant, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another function may be the [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Transpositions) on, for example, $S_4$. i.e; $$\phi: S_4\to \mathbb Z_2$$

Or considering your groups: $$\phi:\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\to \{0\}\times \mathbb Z_3\\(a,b)\mapsto (0,b)$$